# How to check authentication status to an S3 bucket without crashing a shiny app?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, shiny

I have a shiny app that uses data stored on AWS S3; however, my session needs to be refreshed periodically and the app crashes when I try to read data without privileges.

I've taken a look at the source code of `aws.s3` to look for how/when the error is thrown. My goal would be to handle the http response and display it in the app without crashing it.

I've tried wrapping it in `try`:

```r
response <- try(
    aws.s3::head_object(
        object = "test.rds",
        bucket = "mybucket"
    )
)
```

When the session token has expired, this causes a hard error and stops the app instead of returning a "try-error" which could be displayed.

The error reads:

```
Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : 
  Bad Request (HTTP 400).
```

Comment: You might try `tryCatch` instead, a la `tryCatch({
  aws.s3::head_object(
    object = "test.rds",
    bucket = "mybucket"
  )},
  error = function(e){ "there was an error" }
)` - your output will then be "there was an error" if it fails. Or perhaps you could just reauthorize your S3 session every time you pull data.

Comment: Interesting, try still throws the error and stops the app even with `{}` but `tryCatch` works. Post the answer and it's yours ;) @moman822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tryCatch instead, like so:

```
tryCatch({
   aws.s3::head_object( object = "test.rds", bucket = "mybucket" )
 }, 
 error = function(e){ "there was an error" } 
)
```

your output will then be "there was an error" if it fails.

I think the difference w.r.t. `try` is that an expression wrapped in `try` will evaluate the error and move on to the next line if it does cause an error (where otherwise it stops). So in your example an error is being saved to `response`, but `tryCatch` allows you to save something in its place. Try running these lines:

```
sum(c("x","y")); print(5+5)

try(sum(c("x","y"))); print(5+5)

tryCatch({sum(c("x","y"))}, error = function(e){print("fail")}); print(5+5)
```